# How to quit selenium-webdriver with an event listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver

**The context.**

I am running several instances of selenium webdriver in an Electron application.
A user is able to choose how many instances run at the same time, the total amount of instances to run and launch an action (eg scrolling a webpage). I think that this question can be generalized to simply running a chain of async functions in parallel. But i thought there might be some selenium exclusive ways to approaching this.

**The problem.**

I am trying to implement a stop button. It should close all running instances of webdriver. We know how many instances are running at the moment, and the total amount the user selected.

**The code snippet.**

```js
 $('#startAction').on('click', async function() {

        //i deleted irrelevant stuff, there is some validation going on above
        //selectedProfiles is an object with some info about webdriver instances the user selected

        let uuid, browser, ws;
        let promiseMs = [],
            p;
        const streams = parseInt(document.getElementById('streams').value);

        const launchMain = async() => {

            for (let i = 1; i < Object.keys(selectedProfiles).length + 1; i += streams) {

                //i didn't opt for simply running for (let val in selectedProfiles)
                //because we needed to launch only the selected amount of drivers at the same times

                for (let val = i; val < streams + i; val++) {

                    p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        uuid = selectedProfiles[val].uuid;
                        browser = selectedProfiles[val].browser;

                        switch (action) {

                            case 'smart_cookie_robot':
                                {

                                    const url = document.getElementById('actions_input').value;

                                    const launch = async() => {

                                        let capabilities;
                                        if (browser == 'mimic') {
                                            capabilities = Capabilities.chrome();
                                        }
                                        if (browser == 'stealthfox') {
                                            capabilities = Capabilities.firefox();
                                        }
                                        ws = await startProfile(uuid);
                                        let driver = await new Builder()
                                            .usingServer(ws)
                                            .withCapabilities(capabilities)
                                            .build();

                                        drivers.push(driver);

                                        resolve(cooking(driver, url));

                                    }

                                    validate(url) ? launch() : err();

                                    break;

                                }

                            default:

                                {
                                    //there are some other cases, i think they are irrelevant
                                    reject(appendLogsFile('Something went wrong. Try again.'));
                                }

                        }
                    });
                    promiseMs.push(p);
                }

                await Promise.all(promiseMs).then(() => {
                    console.log('One of the threads resolved successfully');
                    promiseMs = [];
                })
                
            }
        }

        streams > Object.keys(selectedProfiles).length ?
            createError(document.querySelector('.profiles_error_wrapper'), 
            'Thread amount should be lower than selected profiles amount') :
            launchMain();

    });
```

**Possible solutions**

1. I tried to make a `quit` boolean variable and an event listener for the stop button. Before running anything in `cooking()` - the function with the action algorithm would check if quit is false. That worked, but it is a bad solution. It would wait for everything in the loop in cooking() to finish first.
2. *Forcing* `driver.quit()` into every running instance of webdriver. I don't know how to interrupt into the running async chain and whether this is possible at all.
3. Using subprocesses. It seems like the best one to me. It should be possible to launch every instance of webdriver in it's own subprocess and then simply kill those when a user clicks the stop button.
4. Something i don't see. This is the main reason i decided to ask this question here - I am sure that I simply miss something obvious.

Comment: The code you added is just javascript, selenium is not being used.

Comment: @Jortega you can see the webdriver initialization in the `launch()` function. Other selenium logic is in the `cooking()` function. But i think it is irrelevant, since it is simply a chain of `await driver.get()` and `await driver.executeScript()` functions

Comment: maybe poll using setTimeout?  Maybe use a proxy object per webdriver?... never tried this sort of thing in Javascript and it always makes my brain hurt.  In Java you have a "propertyChangeListener" which helps dispatch things back to the main run thread. (btw, don't mistake "asynchronous" with "multi-threaded"... javascript is not really multi-threaded...so your drivers aren't going to run simultaneously.  Selenium is not functionally async either...)